# How to replace parentheses in a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my data set I need to replace a value in a column called `_name`. I want to run an update statement where i can remove the opening and closing parentheses of the data

This is my current data:

```
Section (2010)
```

It should become:

```
Section 2010
```

`2010` is dynamic and it can be anything

How can I replace these values in a T-SQL statement?

Comment: Use REPLACE() with an UPDATE statement

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = REPLACE(REPLACE(columnName,'(',''),')','')
```

Comment: Sure there are alternatives but they wouldn't be as clean. This is the perfect use case for REPLACE @Intimate